# Is it possible to resize a grid and have all items be responsive to the new size?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a div with `display: grid` inside I have multiple 3 `divs` for each items.

```css
.test-container {
  //width: 10px;
  //height: 10px;
}

.coin-chart-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1fr;
  //width: 10px;
  //height: 10px;
}

.coin-chart-grid-item-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.coin-chart-grid-item-2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.coin-chart-grid-item-3 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-container">
  <div class="coin-chart-grid">
    <div class="coin-chart-grid-item-1">
      Some Text
    </div>
    <div class="coin-chart-grid-item-2">
      Some Text
    </div>
    <div class="coin-chart-grid-item-3">
      <LineChart class="coin-chart" :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I set the Linechart to responsive. But when I try to case everything in the `div` `coin-chart-grid` and resize that `div` the entire thing just moves down. How can this be?

Comment: working with `1fr` units and resizing can cause issues because the grid templet will try to make every cell the same size. try a different approach maybe with `minmax` or separate grid/flex

Comment: Minmax doesn't fix it sadly